# Migrating 2 CommonsChunksPlugin to Webpack 4's splitChunks

Tags: webpack, commonschunkplugin

I have these settings in a Webpack 2.x config file and I'm migrating to Webpack 4. I know `CommonsChunkPlugin` is deprecated and I should use `optimization.splitChunks`, but I couldn't find anywhere in the docs on how to convert two `CommonsChunkPlugin` instances.

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'common',
        minChunks: Infinity
    }),
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    chunks: ["vendor", "app"],
    minChunks: 2
}),
```

How can I get the same results from the above settings with `optimization.splitChunks`?